# Div number check and setInterval don't work correct together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following script to check if the number of an div is actually matching or not. However the script fails. Maybe I have to convert the number for jQuery? Does jQuery not understand `"2.3"` as number?

```js
var Test = setInterval(TestMethod, 4000);

function TestMethod() {
  if ($(".result").not(':contains("2.3")')) {
    console.log("field not contains 2.3");
    clearInterval(Test);
  } else {
    console.log("field contains 2.3");
    clearInterval(Test);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result">
  2.3
</div>
```

My fiddle:
[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/fqdo6fx3/)

Comment: [`if ($(".result:contains(2.3)").length === 0) {`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/fqdo6fx3/3/)

Comment: @Tushar comparing a jQuery object to false will never hit.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan True. Thought it'll return boolean. Fixed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because your logic is using a jQuery object in an `if` condition. A selector *always* returns an object, even if it matched no elements in the DOM, and as such is coerced to `true` in your condition - hence the issue.

To fix this you need to amend your logic to check the `length` of the returned object to see how many elements it matched:

```js
var Test = setInterval(TestMethod, 4000);

function TestMethod() {
  if ($('.result:contains("2.3")').length == 0) {
    console.log("field not contains 2.3");
    clearInterval(Test);
  } else {
    console.log("field contains 2.3");
    clearInterval(Test);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result">
  2.3
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try length and check if it is not equal to 0

```
    var Test = setInterval(TestMethod, 4000);

function TestMethod() {

        if($(".result").not(':contains(2.3)').length != 0) {
      alert("field not contains 2.3");
      clearInterval(Test);
        }

        else {
            alert("field contains 2.3");
      clearInterval(Test);
        }

}
```

you can check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fqdo6fx3/5/)

Comment: Yes, you are right, like @Rory McCrossan says. Also thx for your way and support!

Comment: Happy to help always